# In a Windows Forms application, how to only close the first form?

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, winforms, application-framework

I have a strange problem with a Windows Forms Application. I have multiple forms open, each one corresponding to a file. When I close the first one, all others are also closed and the program is exited. However, when closing one of the other forms, I do not experience such a behaviour.

Searching for this, I found [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289529%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on MSDN but it does not help me.

So, how do I do this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your Shutdown mode to `When Last form closes` instead of `When Startup form closes`

You can find this setting in:

`Project properties>Application Tab>Windows Application framework properties>Shutdown mode`

These should be fairly self explanatory settings

Comment: Awesome! I totally missed this one.